# Oracle -SQL- Select values based on a long list using where condition

Tags: sql, oracle, list, select, where-clause

I have a long list (over 2000) of phone numbers, and I want to select values where phone numbers are in the list. Can any one tell me how to do it efficiently using sql? Thank you!

The method I know is :

```
select name, date from table where phone in ('8001234567','8011234567',....)
```

this method lists all the phone numbers in the where condition. Is there any other method, such as I can create a list in some file, then select from the file?

Thank you.

Comment: How about putting the phone numbers in a table?

Comment: I agree with @Nick. Besides, IN is restricted to 1000 elements so you can't put 2000 numbers in there just like that. Also, it is close to a *suicide* to maintain such a list.

Comment: Thank you NickW, but I don't have privileges to create tables...

Comment: @goosepea , then make a temp table

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a one-time query and you don't need to maintain this list, you can do this with a CTE:

```
with phone_list as (
    select '1234567890' as phone from dual union all
    select '2345678901' as phone from dual union all
    ...
    select '9999999999' as phone from dual
)
select name, date
  from table t
 inner join phone_list pl on pl.phone = t.phone
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example. I'm using PL/SQL function in a WITH clause of a query.

**Setup**

```
create table phone_list (id number(10), name varchar2(100), phone_number varchar2(20));

insert into phone_list (id, name , phone_number )
select level, 
       'Name' || lpad(to_char(level),4,'_'),
       '001' || to_char(55521239 + level) 
  from dual
connect by level <= 2000;
```

**Query**

```
with
/**testing_function*/
function is_number_in_list(phone_number varchar2) return number 
is
  type t_var_tab is table of varchar2(20);
  phone_list t_var_tab;
  /**Helper procedure*/
  procedure add(p_list in out t_var_tab , p_val varchar2)
  is 
  begin
    p_list.extend;
    p_list(p_list.last) := p_val;
  end;
begin
   phone_list := t_var_tab();
   -- list of Numbers to test
   add(phone_list,'00155522167');
   add(phone_list,'00155522168');
   add(phone_list,'00155522169');
   --
  if phone_number  member of phone_list then 
    return 1 ;
  else 
    return 0;
  end if;
end;
select * from phone_list pl
where is_number_in_list(phone_number) = 1;
```

The example shows a bit of using collections in PL/SQL. But if you only can use SQL, you should use the Solution from @eaolson. *KISS-Principle*

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of your suggestions.
I don't have privileges to create tables, even tempt tables, so finally I solved the problem using the query below:

```
    select name, date 
    from table
    where phone in ('123456788','987654321',...,'123456789')  --first 1000 numbers 
    union
    select name, date
    from table
    where phone in ('223456788','987654320',...,'223456789')  ---next 1000 numbers
```

It's quite like what @eaolson suggested except you can list 1000 phone numbers each time.